# CakePHP Dynamically Add new Forms (WYSIWYG)

Tags: php, html, cakephp, wysiwyg

I've been asked to create a CakePHP plugin that would allow users to dynamically generate forms. This doesn't sound too hard in and of itself (pull fields from DB, figure out what kind of input, show in HTML), but I don't understand how I can "save" the forms to a new page.

From my understanding, Wordpress circumvents this problem by storing all data in the database, and can use shortcodes to just "insert" the form into another page. Seeing that CakePHP handles relies on CTP files to define views (and not Database fields), I don't see any simple approach to doing this.

Is this goal of a WYSIWYG form editor possible in CakePHP (without having to resort to terrible practices like editing CTP/PHP files from within the app)? If so, can you point me towards some strategies I can use to develop this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you do with the dynamic form, to me it sounds like you're describing two totally different things.

- Save the structure of the generated form somehow in the DB, key/value, serialized via php or as json object
- Return the data, set it to the view
- Write a helper that turns the structure that describes the form again in

  - The editable version, restore the form
  - Parses the structure and returns the HTML of whatever the fields of the form should do
- You'll have to write your own parser that looks for things like [gallery id=1] and replace that with the result of a function call. Assuming that this is what you want to do. So you'll have to map the "gallery" to a functional call. I think the best here would be to use requestAction()

The *.ctp files are what WP considers it's template files, and honestly, Wordpress is just a horrible awkward piece of software from a developer perspective.

Comment: Perhaps I can elaborate a bit more (not sure if it will affect your answer). Much like Wordpress offers plugins that allows end users to design forms, this plugin is supposed to allow for the same. The forms should be put onto a new page (i.e. a page not previously on the system). Can Cake do this without serious modification (like writing a custom parser)?

Comment: Thats exactly what I figured, but I didnt want to object to it as impossible before seriously considering some different approaches to the problem. Thank you.